# How can I learn my AZURE SQL SERVER url and connected to Postman API

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, postman, azure-sql-database

My database is in the Azure SQL server. I can access the server name but not the URL of the server.

Also, in my `launchSettings.json` file, how should I describe the URL and port? I research on the internet but I don't understand.

Here is my `launchSettings.json`:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "location-software.database.windows.net,1433/", // I added it was localhost
      "sslPort": 1433 //I added it was 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Clean.Architecture.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "location-software.database.windows.net,1433/"  //Also, it was localhost
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ... why  are you trying to access a **database server** with an **HTTP client**?

Answer (score -1):

State your protocol in the value. `http` or `https`
In your `applicationUrl` value, state the value like this: 
`"https://location-software.database.windows.net,1433/"`